# Stopwatch time always zero

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I've implemented a calculation into my code in which the pc adds all the numbers between 0 and 999999999 together and outputs the answer. This process takes a few seconds between when the button is pressed and the answer is displayed on screen. Now I want to have a stopwatch or timer in place that when I hit the button it begins and stops whenever the answer appears on screen and tells me how long it took. Below is what I implemented however i'm being hit with "00:00:00". Am I wrong in assuming that with this its just start on button press and after for loop stop and display time?

```
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 275, 300, 25), "Add All numbers between 1 and 999999999"))
        {
            AddAllNumbersMax();
            stopWatch.Start();
        }

    }
    GUI.TextArea(new Rect(275, 100, 300, 300), _messageLog);
}

void AddAllNumbersMax()
{
    int max = 999999999;
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<=max; i++) 
    {
        result += i;

    }
    _messageLog += result + "\n";
    stopWatch.Stop ();
    _messageLog += stopWatch.Elapsed;

}
```

UPDATE**

Thanks for the quick replies, I see where I went wrong now! Unfortunately with such a low rep I can't upvote your answers :( but thanks anyways! Early mornings to blame!

Comment: Think about *when* you start the stopwatch in relation to the calculation ...

Comment: You call AddAllNumbersMax() which stops the stopwatch, THEN you start the stopwatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stopping the stopwatch before you start it

try:

```
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 275, 300, 25), "Add All numbers between 1 and 999999999"))
        {
            stopWatch.Start();
            AddAllNumbersMax();

        }

    GUI.TextArea(new Rect(275, 100, 300, 300), _messageLog);
}

void AddAllNumbersMax()
{
    int max = 999999999;
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<=max; i++) 
    {
        result += i;

    }
    _messageLog += result + "\n";
    stopWatch.Stop ();
    _messageLog += stopWatch.Elapsed;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to measure the run time of AddAllNumbersMax(), in which case you have to start the Stopwatch before the method call, and stop it afterwards:

```
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 275, 300, 25), "Add All numbers between 1 and 999999999"))
{
  stopWatch.Start();
  AddAllNumbersMax();
  stopWatch.Stop();
  // Do something with elapsed time
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AddAllNumbersMax();
stopWatch.Start();
```

This will *first* execute `AddAllNumbersMax`—which in turns calls `stopWatch.Stop()` and reads the elapsed time—and only *then* it will start the time.

If you are going to measure the time `AddAllNumbersMax` takes, it’s probably a good idea to start the stopwatch in there too. Or move the whole stopwatch business out of the method and put it around the call.

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious because the program first gonna execute your AddAllNumbersMax() and when this operation will end they app will start the timer.
you should do it like this:

```
stopWatch.Start();
AddAllNumbersMax();
stopWatch.Stop();
```